# Why do i get this error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def diameter(Points):
    '''Given a list of 2d points, returns the pair that's farthest apart.'''
    diam,pair = max([((p[0]-q[0])**2 + (p[1]-q[1])**2, (p,q))
                     for p,q in rotatingCalipers(Points)])
    return pair


n=int(input())

a=[]

max=0

for i in xrange(n):
    m,n=map(int,raw_input().split())
    a.append((m,n))
    diameter(a)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geocheat1.py", line 56, in <module>
    diameter(a)
  File "geocheat1.py", line 43, in diameter
    for p,q in rotatingCalipers(Points)])
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Post the stack trace

Comment: *In the question, not as a comment*

Comment: `max=0` -> `diam,pair = max(...)`

Comment: Yup. This is why you shouldn't shadow built-ins.

Comment: Sorry @juanpa.arrivillaga New here.

Comment: What is `rotatingCalipers` may it's declared as a integer in somewhere in your code.

Comment: thanks @JeffMercado Got it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the Traceback it's clear than you are trying to call `int` object, So `rotatingCalipers` may be declared as integer in your code.

See this example you will understand the error,

```
In [1]: a = (1,2,3)
In [2]: list(a)
Out[1]: [1, 2, 3]
In [3]: list = 5
In [4]: list(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-61edcfee5862> in <module>()
----> 1 list(a)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```